# ASP.NET MVC validationMessageFor as bootstrap popover on the textbox

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have a login page created with ASP.NET MVC, I want the MVC ValidationMessageFor to be displayed as bootstrap popout and over the corresponding text box.

This is somewhat working but not exactly. Popout is coming but not getting displayed over the textbox and also ValidationMessageFor is getting displayed separately as well. Which should not.

Any ideas or help will be appreciated.

[image]

```
    @model x.Areas.Account.Models.User

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Login</title>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    <script>
        $(function () {    
            $(".field-validation-error[data-toggle='popover']").each(function () {
                var x = $(this).text();

                if (x) {
                    $(this).popover({
                        content: x,
                        trigger: "manual",
                        template: "<div class=\"popover\"><div class=\"arrow\"></div><div class=\"popover-inner\"><div class=\"popover-content\"><p></p></div></div></div>"
                    });
                    $(this).popover('show');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    <style>
        .required:after {
            content: "*";
            font-weight: bold;
            color: red;
        }

        .input-validation-error {
            border-color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Login</legend>
                <div>
                    @Html.LabelFor(u => u.UserName, new { @class = "required" })
                    <div>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.UserName)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.UserName, null, new { @class = "text-danger", @data_toggle = "popover", @data_placement = "top" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    @Html.LabelFor(u => u.Password, new { @class = "required" })
                    <div>
                        @Html.PasswordFor(u => u.Password)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.Password, null, new { @class = "text-danger", @data_toggle = "popover", @data_placement = "right" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div style="margin-top:5px;">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Log In" />
                </div>
                <div style="margin-top:5px; margin-left:5px;">
                    <input type="button" id="btnErrLog" class='overlay' value="Error Log" />
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    }
</body>
</html>
```

Update 1: Applying suggested reply with success :)

```
$("input[data-toggle=popover]").each(function () {
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            var validator = $('[data-valmsg-for=' + id + ']');
            var msg = $(validator).html();

            if (msg) {
                $(this).popover({
                    content: msg,
                    trigger: "manual",
                    template: "<div class=\"popover\"><div class=\"arrow\"></div><div class=\"popover-inner\"><div class=\"popover-content\"><p></p></div></div></div>"
                });
                $(this).popover('show');
                $(validator).hide();
            }
        });

<div>
                @Html.LabelFor(u => u.UserName, new { @class = "required" })
                <div>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.UserName, new { @class = "text-danger", @data_toggle = "popover", @data_placement = "top" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.UserName, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                @Html.LabelFor(u => u.Password, new { @class = "required" })
                <div>
                    @Html.PasswordFor(u => u.Password, new { @class = "text-danger", @data_toggle = "popover", @data_placement = "right" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.Password, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Your javascript code is running on document.ready(). I am getting empty 'msg' from validator when it runs. How you are getting the 'msg'??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you should place your `@data_toggle = "popover"` classes not in `ValidationMessageFor` but in `TextBoxFor` and `PasswordFor` helper.

Then change jquery selector from `$(".field-validation-error[data-toggle='popover']")` to `$("input[data-toggle='popover']")`

At last you should change your js to get right message in `x` variable.

Comment: thanks, works like charm :) I had to manually hide the ValidationMessageFor in jquery method that shows popover. Is there any automatic way that hides it...